# How to init an ArgoCD application from a git repository

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, gitops

I would like to create an argoCD application right from the git repository, ie the gitOps way. I already created a CRD file for the application which looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: default
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
    - CreateNamespace=true
  project: default
  source:
    path: clusters/helm-chart
    repoURL: https://github.com/user/my-repo.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    helm:
      values: |
        image:
          repository: user/my-image
          pullPolicy: Always
          tag: xxx
```

My current workflow is to apply this CRD to my cluster with `k apply -f application.yaml`.

**Question:** how can I instruct ArgoCD to go and sync/create the application I have defined at `https://github.com/user/my-repo.git` without first creating that application "manually"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point you have to manually apply a manifest to your ArgoCD instance.

You can limit that to a single manifest if you utilize the [app-of-apps](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/) pattern, in which you have a repository that contains all your ArgoCD application manifests.

You can also create [ApplicationSets](https://argocd-applicationset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to automatically generate ArgoCD applications from templates based on the content of a git repository, the names of clusters registered with ArgoCD, and other data.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I ended up creating an application set to create all the applications at once